# Read Styles in excel sheets in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx

is there a way to read the style of a column or cell in excel sheet in nodejs? I'm using `xlsx` lib but I am okay with using any other lib that provide this info. to be precise I need to know if a column or cell is bold or not while reading it.

Answer (score 2):

The ['excel.js`](https://github.com/exceljs) did good job to get style and more other functions.

Demo - get `B1` and `C1` cell's styles.
B1 - Arial, 12 px size, bold
C1 - Calibri, 20 px, Italic

[image]

Code

```js
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');

const wb = new ExcelJS.Workbook();

const fileName = 'test-style.xlsx';

wb.xlsx.readFile(fileName).then(() => {
    
    const ws = wb.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
    const b1_font = ws.getCell('B1').font
    console.log(b1_font);

    const c1_font = ws.getCell('C2').font
    console.log(c1_font);

}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
});
```

Result

```
$ node read.js
{ bold: true, size: 12, color: { theme: 1 }, name: 'Arial', family: 2 }
{
  size: 20,
  color: { theme: 1 },
  name: 'Calibri',
  family: 2,
  scheme: 'minor'
}
```

[image]

More detail information in [here](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#fonts)
and [here](https://zetcode.com/javascript/exceljs/)

#### Note - The standard of [SheetJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) **Do Not** support style reading.

But the Pro version is supported.

Tested code.

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

const workbook = XLSX.readFile('test-style.xlsx', {cellStyles: true});

function getCellStyle(worksheet, cellAddress) {
    const cell = worksheet[cellAddress];
    if (!cell || !cell.s) {
        return null;
    }
    return cell.s;
}

const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];

let cellAddress = 'B1';

let cellStyle= getCellStyle(worksheet, cellAddress);
if (cellStyle) {
    console.log(`Style for ${sheetName} cell ${cellAddress} in sheet '${sheetName}':`, cellStyle);
} else {
    console.log(`No style found for cell ${cellAddress} in sheet '${sheetName}'`);
}

cellAddress = 'C2';
cellStyle= getCellStyle(worksheet, cellAddress);
if (cellStyle) {
    console.log(`Style for ${sheetName} cell ${cellAddress} in sheet '${sheetName}':`, cellStyle);
} else {
    console.log(`No style found for cell ${cellAddress} in sheet '${sheetName}'`);
}
```

Result

```
$ node read-by-xlsx.js
Style for Sheet1 cell B1 in sheet 'Sheet1': { patternType: 'none' }
Style for Sheet1 cell C2 in sheet 'Sheet1': { patternType: 'none' }
```

Comment: I'm late to the party, but I still need to ask. Does xlsx/sheetjs allow reading cell styles (b/i/s/u)? Is it only available in pro version?

Comment: @DoomBot, It is not part of Excel. It is open source JavaScript library, called `exceljs`  detail information in [here](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs)

Comment: Thanks. What I was really asking (I guess I was unclear) is if you maybe know, if `xlsx` library has access to cell styles, as I can't seem to be able to access them. https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Comment: I heared  too that cell styles are only supported in the Pro version of SheetJS (also known as xlsx-pro). The standard SheetJS library (xlsx) does not support reading cell styles. I confirmed with standard option.  I tested this code for file read `XLSX.readFile('test-style.xlsx', {cellStyles: true})`

Comment: yea, tried that as well and couldn't get the cell styles. I though that I might be making a mistake somewhere and that's the reason I can't get the style. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: I updated my answer, and I tested it.

Comment: I'd give you another upvote if I could :)