# Does SheetJS/xlsx (nodejs module) have functionality to access Excels cell style (b/i/u/s)?

Tags: node.js, cell, xlsx, sheetjs

This is more of a general question then anything else.

Am I correct in assuming that xlsx/sheetjs does not allow reading the cells style?

I can access cell.h, which returns the cells string, with style ie.`<b>hello</b> world`, but I can not access cell.style which would return bold (cell.s returns the style of background and foreground, but not the cells style as such (bold,italic,underline etc)).

As far as I understand this option is only available in pro?

sources:
[so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75302884/read-styles-in-excel-sheets-in-js), [gh1](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/74), [gh2](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/128)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sheetjs`/`xlsx` does **not** allow access to cell styles. It is only allowed in pro version (`xlsx-pro`).

I got confirmation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75302884/read-styles-in-excel-sheets-in-js/75304338?noredirect=1#comment133853638_75304338) discussion / comment thread.